# postgresql: How do i add a column which stores the time of creation of the row with timestamp automatically

Tags: postgresql

In postgresql I have a table already created with millions of rows.

Currently I have the following table

```
id | name | t1 | t2 | t3 |
--------------------------
```

I want to have

```
id | name | t1 | t2 | t3 | creation_time |
------------------------------------------
```

And the creation_time should be time_stamp with timezone. and automatically added whenever a new row is inserted.

HOw can I do this

Also since there are so many existing rows. I would like to add NULL for them. and for the new rows I want to use the current creation time.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a default value:

```
-- will default to NULL
ALTER TABLE mytab ADD creation_time timestamp with time zone;

ALTER TABLE mytab ALTER creation_time SET DEFAULT current_timestamp;
```

You don't set the default when you create the column, otherwise the default value will be applied to all existing rows.

The alternative is a trigger (which will not perform as well):

```
-- will default to NULL
ALTER TABLE mytab ADD creation_time timestamp with time zone;

CREATE FUNCTION set_creation_time() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   NEW.creation_time = current_timestamp;
   RETURN NEW;
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER set_creation_time BEFORE INSERT ON mytab FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_creation_time();
```

Comment: whats the difference between using triggers and using `default` i.e  `ALTER TABLE mytab ADD creation_time timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now();`

Comment: That would set the column to the current timestamp for all existing rows. But it is a good idea; I will extend the answer.

Comment: I want to set NULL for all existing rows. BUt for future created rows I want it to add automatically system current time with timezone

Comment: Right, that's what both my solutions do.

Comment: Also I see that `current_timestamp` does not follow the `id`. Some places higher `id` has  `timestamp` lower than previous

Comment: Yes, that is normal.